WPF Attached Property cannot be found
I have made a Template for a TextBox control that contains two buttons:
<ControlTemplate x:Key="TwoButtonField" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.Column="1" Content="Update" Click="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:CustomFieldBox.UpdateClick)}"/>
        <Button BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Grid.Column="2" Content="Insert" Click="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:CustomFieldBox.InsertClick)}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

Since I'm planning to set different event handlers for each instance of this template, I was trying to implement a couple of attached properties, one for each button.
public class CustomFieldBox : DependencyObject {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InsertClickProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InsertClick", typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(TextBox));

    public static void SetInsertClick(UIElement element, RoutedEventHandler e) {
        element.SetValue(InsertClickProperty, e);
    }
    public static RoutedEventHandler GetInsertClick(UIElement element) {
        return (RoutedEventHandler)element.GetValue(InsertClickProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty UpdateClickProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UpdateClick", typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(TextBox));

    public static void SetUpdateClick(UIElement element, RoutedEventHandler e) {
        element.SetValue(UpdateClickProperty, e);
    }
    public static RoutedEventHandler GetUpdateClick(UIElement element) {
        return (RoutedEventHandler)element.GetValue(UpdateClickProperty);
    }
}

This is how I indent to use them
<TextBox Template="{StaticResource TwoButtonField}" local:CustomFieldBox.UpdateClick="FieldUpdateHandle">

When I launch the window an XAMLParseException is thrown saying there isnt any public UpdateClick property inside of CustomFieldBox.
I'm all sorts of confused on how to make it work, I don't understand what I did wrong and how to fix it. Please help

The third argument to RegisterAttached must be typeof(CustomFieldBox).

Also note that for declaring attached properties, a class does not need to be derived from DependencyObject. It could instead be declared static.
